# Install nvidia driver in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

My additional drivers show that it is using nvidia-375. [image]

But nvidia x server settings is empty.

[image]

Also if I run this command

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

It outputs `cat: /proc/driver/nvidia/version: No such file or directory`. So what I do to keep nvidia working?

Comment: Have you installed other driver version before?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.